# Why cant my code behind page acces variables in View Model

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why doesnt my View recognize email and password strings from View Model.
It says that email and password dont exist in current context. Can someone tell me why doesnt this code work and explain solution?
this is code in View:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Papucometar.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
namespace Papucometar.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginUI : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginUI()
        {
            var vm = new LoginViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = vm;
            vm.DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Login, try again", "OK");
            InitializeComponent();

            email.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Password.Focus();
            };

            Password.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And this is ViewModel code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Papucometar.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Action DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private string Email;
        public string email
        {
            get { return Email; }
            set
            {
                Email = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
            }
        }
        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                password = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
            }
        }
        public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
        }
        public void OnSubmit()
        {
            if (email != "macoratti@yahoo.com" || password != "secret")
            {
                DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliSense says that these variables dont exist. I cant figure out why they cant see each other.
This is xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Papucometar.View.LoginUI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Papucometar.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="local:LoginViewModel"
             BackgroundColor="#112B47">
    <ContentPage.Content>  
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40">  
        <BoxView HeightRequest="10"/>  
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" Source="maco.jpg"/>  
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#BF043055" HasShadow="False">  
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">  
                <Entry x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email"   
                       PlaceholderColor="White" HeightRequest="40"   
                       Keyboard="Email"  
                       TextColor="White"/>  
                <Entry x:Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Senha"   
                       PlaceholderColor="White" HeightRequest="40"   
                       IsPassword="True"  
                       TextColor="White"/>  
            </StackLayout>  
        </Frame>  
        <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="Login" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                BackgroundColor="#088da5" />  
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing VM properties with controls in your XAML.  Focus and Completed are events fired by UI elements

Comment: I added xaml code to question if you could look what is wrong

Comment: there is no control in your XAML named `email` and there is no VM property named `email` either

Comment: I added wrong xaml i edited it now

Comment: And there is VM property named email  public string email
        {
            get { return Email; }
            set
            {
                Email = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
            }
        }

Comment: `x:Name="Email"` but in the code you have `email.Completed`

Comment: Please change your code to use standard capitalization conventions. `private string email; public string Email { get { return email; } …`. Xaml only sees **properties** (get/set). It does not see fields. In your code, it cannot see Email, because that is not a property.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I notice that you use the following code in code behind to add a Completed event to an Entry，

```
email.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    Password.Focus();
 };
```

But in your xaml, you set  `x:Name="Email"`

```
 <Entry x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email}"
```

So you know it's case sensitive. The **email** in code behind refers to the Entry (with x:Name="email") set in xaml instead of email property in ViewModel. That's why you got *"email does not exist in the current context"*.

By the way, if you want to access the ViewModel variables from code behind, you could use:

```
var password = vm.Password;
```

============**Origin answer**======

You have done most of the work. But capitalization conventions and some details should be paid more attention to, as ToolmakerSteve mentioned.

In the ViewModel, you define the Email property in this way:

```
    private string Email;
    public string email
    {
        get { return Email; }
        set
        {
            Email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
        }
    }
```

That means **Email** string is a **private** variable and only in the same class can access it.

If an outside class want to access it, it can be done with properties. That's **email** property in your code. So other class can only access the Email string through email property, to be explicit, through
getter in email property.

Another is capitalization conventions. Usually we set the private field to lower case while the property name to upper case.

To conclude, you may change email property to this:

```
    private string email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Email)));
        }
    }
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for helping this worked fine till few hours ago now when I tested app it just wont allow me to delete my value from entry app just crash

Comment: @St3fKe I saw your new post. It cashed because passing a Null to int.Parse. No problem with my answer based on this thread.